# How to obtain the following order in the result set from the following data stored in MS SQL server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

Following is the order in which the records are originally stored in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Locations
(
Name varchar(255),
Description varchar(255),
Parent varchar(255)
); 

insert into locations values('L1','Parent Locaton1',null); 
insert into locations values('SLC','Sub location B','L1'); 
insert into locations values('L2','Parent Locaton2',null);
insert into locations values('SLY','Sub Location Y','L2');
insert into locations values('SLZ','Sub Location Z','L2');
insert into locations values('SLA','Sub location A','L1'); 
insert into locations values('SLB','Sub location B','L1');
```

Original Stored Table:

[image: Original Table]

Required output order:

[image]

I am basically looking for a solution without cursors or temporary tables. Derived tables are fine though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why @vkp deleted the answer.  It appears to be correct for your data, unless you have multiple levels in your hierarchy:

```
select l.*
from locations l
order by coalesce(l.parent, l.name), name;
```

More specifically, if you want to have the parent always be first, you might not want to depend on the name:

```
select l.*
from locations l
order by coalesce(l.parent, l.name),
         (case when l.parent is null then 1 else 2 end),
         name;
```

Comment: awesome! works perfect. Yes I only have one level nesting

Answer (score 2):

You can use `coalesce` in `order by`.

```
select * from locations
order by coalesce(parent,name),case when parent is null then 0 else 1 end,name
```